# Unable to pass Collection to views via ViewComposer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a view composer:

```
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use App\Models\FloatingMenu;

class FloatingMenuComposer {

  protected $floatingMenu;

  public function __construct()
   {
       // Dependencies automatically resolved by service container...
       $this->floatingMenu = FloatingMenu::all();
   }


    public function compose(View $view) 
    {
       $floatingMenuItems = null;
       foreach($this->floatingMenu as $menu){
         if ($view->getName() == $menu->page) {
           $floatingMenuItems = $menu->floatingMenuItems()->get();
         }
       }
       $view->with('floatingMenuItems' , $floatingMenuItems);
    }
}
```

If I dump the $floatingMenuItems variable in the view I get null. However If I dump the $floatingMenuItems variable in the compose() function it definitely contains a collection of data.

If I swop out:

```
$view->with('floatingMenuItems' , $floatingMenuItems);
```

with:

```
$view->with('floatingMenuItems' , "Random String");
```

then it prints out the random string in the view when I dump the $floatingMenuItems variable. So for some reason it is not allowing me to pass a collection to my view via the view composer.

How can i get around this?

Comment: not sure about the issue, but you can try passing `$floatingMenuItems->toArray()` and check if it is available in view. I too have the view composer which pass the model data as a collection in my view, never seen this issue with it.

Comment: @jaysingkar it then fails with 'Call to a member function toArray() on null'. it's so strange as, if I dump the variable before that, it shows the collection.

Comment: in your for each loop, how many times `if()` statement is executing ?

Comment: one or more than one?

Comment: not sure if this will work, but you can try changing `null` to `$floatingMenuItems = collect()`;

Comment: @jaysingkar the if statement executes once. `$floatingMenuItems = collect()` doesn't help as `$floatingMenuItems` is then just an empty collection. It's as if `view()->with()` is not seeing the variable after it has been set.

Comment: Change your placement of returning view inside if statement.(since it is executing only once). check my answer

Comment: What will `$menu->floatingMenuItems()` return? I think the issue is this statement `$menu->floatingMenuItems()->get()`

Comment: @MinaAbadir this returns the collection of values in the from executing the query. reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: @MinaAbadir the value returned by this method is correct as Sean has confirmed this by using `var_dump()`

Comment: Would you share your view code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your placement of returning view inside if statement.(since it is executing only once)

```
public function compose(View $view) 
    {
       $floatingMenuItems = collect(); //remove this
       foreach($this->floatingMenu as $menu){
         if ($view->getName() == $menu->page) {
           //$floatingMenuItems = $menu->floatingMenuItems()->get();
           $view->with('floatingMenuItems' , $menu->floatingMenuItems()->get());
         }
       }       
    }
```

Comment: That will not make a difference. Actually the original code is cleaner and more standardized.

Comment: @MinaAbadir I know this is not a standardized approach, but this is the only way to store the value. I tried to read about PHP variable, scope but couldn't find what might be causing the variable to be null while passing to view.

Comment: @MinaAbadir I answered this change, because it will retain the variable value in the code. Your regarding the variable scope will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As long as it's inside the same function, scope won't be an issue

Comment: Moving the returning of the view to inside the if, solved the problem. This makes no sense to me as the scope should not be an issue here.

Comment: glad to hear that you have the issue resolved. However something wrong here. Are you sure you do not have two views with the same name?

Comment: @MinaAbadir if that would have been the case, even this code wouldn't have work.

Comment: @MinaAbadir I don't have much knowledge about the scope, but it seems like the `$floatingMenuItems` variable in for each loop is assign the value to completely different memory space and not the one referred by `$floatingMenuItems` in the function. Though not sure, why

Comment: Probably, the variable is being overwritten in the for loop, so the final variable is nullified.

Comment: As far as I know, we want it to override so that the we can refer to the same variable with changed value outside for loop. But its not the case here

Comment: I tried to gather information about this situation, but couldn't find anything relevant :(

Comment: Thank you for the help @jaysingkar. I find this truly strange

Comment: @SeanRoutledge, I would not personally go with a code that did not work for a specific logical flow. This is a potential bug in the future. You should understand why the first one did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion: 
1. Where did u dump the $floatingMenuItems variable in the compose() function? Inside foreach or outside foreach?
2. You should break the foreach after get floatingMenuItems 
Try it!